# ClassCastException on a class not being used?

Tags: java, classcastexception

I've got a `HashMap<Integer, Object>` and I've got a getter function for it as such:

```
public Boolean getBoolean(int index){
     return (boolean) watcherMap.get(index);
}
```

When calling this class, I get this error

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to
java.lang.Boolean
at com.vobis.onebullet.entity.DataWatcher.getBoolean(DataWatcher.java:36)
at com.vobis.onebullet.entity.Entity.updateLocally(Entity.java:91)
at com.vobis.onebullet.level.Level.updateLevel(Level.java:149)
at com.vobis.onebullet.OneBullet.loop(OneBullet.java:264)
at com.vobis.onebullet.OneBullet.start(OneBullet.java:228)
at com.vobis.onebullet.OneBullet.run(OneBullet.java:125)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

But no where in that function am I casting a String to a boolean?  I'm casting a boolean to an object!

Comment: you are casting an Object to a Boolean, and that object is a String

Comment: Uh.. I was reading it the wrong way around >.> happens when you've been coding for 3 days straight :( I'll take a look into that, it should be a boolean.

Comment: I made the program print out what the value it was casting to a boolean everytime and it said "false" just before it crashed, so how can it be a string?

Comment: Is is a boolean `false` or the string literal "false"?

Comment: `public Boolean getBoolean(int index){
  System.out.println(watcherMap.get(index).getClass());
   return (boolean) watcherMap.get(index);
 }` I tried this, before the crash, nothing is printed, but it says it's on that line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are casting an Object to a Boolean, and that object is instance of `java.lang.String`.
It means that you in some place put

```
watcherMap.put(someInteger,"SomeString");
getBoolean(someInteger);
```

And this will throw a `ClassCastException`

Comment: However, I'm looking everywhere in my code, never at any point is a string added to my HashMap

Comment: Try to debug it ;) .. or put some System.out.println() to see what is, in some place you are adding a `String`, is there a reason to have a map of `<Integer,Object>` downcasting is dangerous.

Comment: class java.lang.Boolean
false
class java.lang.Boolean
false
class java.lang.String
false
I made it print the class type and then the actual value, for some reason, it's just set to a string... ?

Comment: @ShaunWild in some place you are adding a String rather than a Boolean,if your map if it's only of Boolean, why not declare as `Map<Integer,Boolean>`

Comment: I'm an idiot hahaha, because PrintWriter can print any object, I assumed a BufferedReader would read any object,forgetting it turns everything it reads into a string..

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Hashmap is storing (Integer,String) in the situation where it threw this exception. Please remember Object is the parent class of classes in Java and hence it's reference can hold any object.

Answer (score 0):

There wont be any error if you keep

```
watcherMap.put(1, true);
```

or something like

```
watcherMap.put(2, Boolean.FALSE)
```

But definitely an issue if you say

```
watcherMap.put(1, "true");
```

Can you show us what are you putting to watcherMap?